# is there a separate version of nltk downloadable for python3.4.2.?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two versions of python in the system. One is 2.7.2. and the other is 3.4.3. I have made 3.4.3. as my default one. When I install nltk, it says,
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nltk"

OR,
when i give, "sudo pip install -U nltk",it says,

"Requirement already up-to-date: nltk in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from nltk)
Requirement already up-to-date: singledispatch in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from nltk)
Cleaning up..."

How to install nltk for 3.4.3?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pip3.4 instead of pip2.7, which is separate from setting the default version of Python. This should work:

```
$ sudo pip3.4 install -U nltk
```

Comment: Thank you. but, "sudo: pip3.4: command not found" is the reply from the system

Comment: @keerthanaB. you'll need to find the version of pip installed with Python 3.4 (or install it) and run that